# jQuery UI multiple resizable divs not bigger than parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a parent div. The parent div contains five other divs (next to each other). What I'm trying to do, is making these divs resizable with jQuery UI.

The problem (which makes it difficult for me), is that the resizable width of all five divs can't be bigger than the width of the parent div. For example:

- Let's say, the **parent** div has a width of 500px (this is 100% on my screen).
- **Each div inside the parent div** has a width of 100px (includes the margin and border);

When **div 1** is resized from 100px to 200px width, following happened:

- **Div 1** has now a width of 200px.
- **Divs 2, 3, 4 and 5** have a width of 75px (because 500px - 300px = 200px / 4 = 75px each).

I added an example of code and an image below. I used an example I found on StackOverflow and I adjusted it. Why is this example not working correctly? Why are the divs moving to the next line and not stopping at the end of the screen?

Thanks for the help.

[image: Resizable divs]

```html
<style>
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#app {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#resultColumns {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    padding: 10px;
}
.columnContainer {
    min-width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #333333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
    border-left: 1px solid #333333;
}
.lastColumnContainer {
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
}
.columnHeader {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.columnContent {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div id="resultColumns">
                <!-- First Column -->
                <div class="columnContainer">
                    <div class="columnHeader">Title 1</div>
                    <div class="columnContent">Content 1</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Second Column -->
                <div class="columnContainer">
                    <div class="columnHeader">Title 2</div>
                    <div class="columnContent">Content 2</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Third Column -->
                <div class="columnContainer">
                    <div class="columnHeader">Title 3</div>
                    <div class="columnContent">Content 3</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fourth Column -->
                <div class="columnContainer">
                    <div class="columnHeader">Title 4</div>
                    <div class="columnContent">Content 4</div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fifth Column -->
                <div class="columnContainer lastColumnContainer">
                    <div class="columnHeader">Title 5</div>
                    <div class="columnContent">Content 5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    makeResizable();
    function makeResizable() {
        $('#resultColumns .columnContainer:eq(0)').resizable({
            maxWidth: getMaxWidth($('#resultColumns .columnContainer:eq(0)')),
            stop: updateMaxWidth,
            handles: 'e'
        });
        $('#resultColumns .columnContainer:eq(1)').resizable({
            maxWidth: getMaxWidth($('#resultColumns .columnContainer:eq(1)')),
            stop: updateMaxWidth,
            handles: 'e'
        });
        $('#resultColumns .columnContainer:eq(2)').resizable({
            maxWidth: getMaxWidth($('#resultColumns .columnContainer:eq(2)')),
            stop: updateMaxWidth,
            handles: 'e'
        });
        $('#resultColumns .columnContainer:eq(3)').resizable({
            maxWidth: getMaxWidth($('#resultColumns .columnContainer:eq(3)')),
            stop: updateMaxWidth,
            handles: 'e'
        });
        $('#resultColumns .columnContainer:eq(4)').resizable({
            maxWidth: getMaxWidth($('#resultColumns .columnContainer:eq(4)')),
            stop: updateMaxWidth,
            handles: 'e'
        });
    }
    function getMaxWidth(e) {
        return $('#resultColumns').width() - e.siblings().outerWidth() - 10; // 10px for the borders (2px each) - 5 divs in total
    }
    function updateMaxWidth(e, ui) {
        ui.element.siblings().resizable('option', 'maxWidth', getMaxWidth(ui.element.siblings()));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Try to look up `display: grid` https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you must calculate the slices for each resizable, including borders. Initially, you're looking at the first element and calculating the `maxWidth` on the other sibling elements. for your example, that's the other 4 elements.

If you grab one of the other elements, lets say the 3rd one, the other remaining next siblings need to be updated so their `maxWidth` is the portion remaining.

```js
$(function() {
  function getPad(o, d) {
    return parseInt(o.css("padding-" + d));
  }

  function getMaxWidth(o) {
    var mw = parseInt(o.parent().innerWidth()) - (getPad(o.parent(), "left") + getPad(o.parent(), "right"));
    var sbw = 2; // First & Last Border
    o.siblings(".columnContainer").each(function(i, el) {
      sbw += parseInt($(el).width()) + 1; // Inner Border
    });
    return mw - sbw;
  }

  function makeResizable() {
    $('#resultColumns .columnContainer').resizable({
      handles: 'e',
      maxWidth: getMaxWidth($("#resultColumns .first")),
      resize: function(e, ui) {
        console.log($(this).width(), getMaxWidth($(this)));
      },
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).siblings().each(function(i, el) {
          $(el).resizable("option", "maxWidth", getMaxWidth($(el)));
        });
      }
    });
  }

  makeResizable();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#resultColumns {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  padding: 10px;
}

.columnContainer {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  float: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #333333;
}

.last {
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
}

.columnHeader {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.columnContent {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<div id="app">
  <div id="resultColumns">
    <!-- First Column -->
    <div class="columnContainer first">
      <div class="columnHeader">Title 1</div>
      <div class="columnContent">Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Second Column -->
    <div class="columnContainer">
      <div class="columnHeader">Title 2</div>
      <div class="columnContent">Content 2</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Third Column -->
    <div class="columnContainer">
      <div class="columnHeader">Title 3</div>
      <div class="columnContent">Content 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fourth Column -->
    <div class="columnContainer">
      <div class="columnHeader">Title 4</div>
      <div class="columnContent">Content 4</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Fifth Column -->
    <div class="columnContainer last">
      <div class="columnHeader">Title 5</div>
      <div class="columnContent">Content 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You answer is great. Just want to add some consents here.  Based on what the poster wants from its original approach.  There are many issue he/she has to rewrite by himself. What happen if overflow, do he still wants to keep all items on the same line? The `min-width` and the updated new `width` for other containers.
I would just recommend him/her to use something like a  resizable table to keep the consistency like the idea from https://codepen.io/jasongardner/pen/QNOXym

Comment: @Yunhai OP states this: "*Why is this example not working correctly? Why are the divs moving to the next line and not stopping at the end of the screen?*". Your suggestion also good, and there are other options.

Comment: @Twisty, this is the perfect answer! Thank you very much. I didn't realise I was only looking to the first element. That makes sense why it wasn't working properly.

Comment: @Yunhai, thank you for your answer. I can't use a table for the thing I'm coding. I have to use divs. But I will save your codepen-link to my Bookmarks. Maybe for the future.